# Proposal for a Topic of the Week Contest - Urban legends

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We all have heard many silly urban legends in our time.  We could ask questions about them and answer them so that to dispel them.  Things like black belt being black because no one washed them, or *hakama* trailing on the floor, or bowing to *bokken* or ...

Good idea?

Bad idea?

Comment: We'd have to be careful not to tread into skeptics.SE territory, particularly because I fear we'd start validating some of those ridiculous myths.